# If number is equally split?

Tags: java, floating-point

Say we have two textfields:

First textfield - user enters an amount - can be any amount to two decimal places (3456.23, 555555.5, 23.44 etc)

Second textfield - user enters an amount to equally split this by (2, 7, 1 etc)

How can we then  check whether the result of this calculation is an exact split (to two decimal places)? E.g.

```
54.2 / 2 = 27.1 (exact split) returns true
61.05 / 2 = 30.525 (not exact split) returns false
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exact split"? 61.05 / 2 is exactly 30.525

Comment: @Warlord Exact split to two decimal places

Comment: `if (2nd decimal is odd) { won't split evenly }`.

Comment: Except that the divisor is also an input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply value input by 100, modulo by split, and check for zero remainder:

```
(54.20 * 100) % 2 = 0
(61.05 * 100) % 2 = 1
```

Comment: That's not true, what happens if the third decimal place is zero, but there's a non-zero digit in 4th decimal place, or further?

Comment: @Warlord OP states "any amount to two decimal places"

Comment: but he also states that you can divide by other numbers than 2

Comment: (@Warlord BTW, your answer uses modulo 1 which will always have a remainder of zero...)

Comment: @Warlord Yes; my answer is **modulo by split**; so '2' in the example provided or '7' if you so wish...

Comment: no it won't, this is not a classic modular arithmetics, you can also do 0.1 % 1, which is not zero

Comment: @Warlord I'm not familiar with programming environments which implements modulo (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) as you describe - can you help clarify with the details of the environment you're seeing this behavior in?

Comment: Well then, try doing `System.out.println(0.1 % 1);` in Java

Comment: @Warlord as expected from the mathematical definition of modulo, the remainder of dividing 0.1 with 1 is 0.1, including in Java; and, the remainder of dividing 0.1*100 by 1 is 0. I think the confusion here is that OP states the problem is specific to two decimal places, not any more than that. With two decimal places, a multiplication by 100 will turn this into an integer which when divided by the split value has a remainder if it is *not evenly split*; if the remainder is zero, the value is evenly split. This is what I understand the OP's question to be posing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48175/discussion-between-jan-nielsen-and-warlord)

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the result of division by 100 and use modulo to check if it has a non-zero decimal part.

```
if (((number*100) % 1) == 0) {
    // exact
} else {
    // not exact
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is equivalent to "is `number*100` divisible by `split`". You can multiply your `BigDecimal` by 100, convert to `BigInteger`, and use `mod` to check.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the answer as a string, then split it into tokens by the regular expression `[.]` and check the length of the trailing decimals:

```
String decimals = Float.toString(f);
String[] tokens = decimals.split("[.]");
return tokens[1].length() == 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `divide()`method of `BigDecimal`:

```
public static boolean isExactSplit (BigDecimal number, int nbParts) {
    try {
        number.divide(new BigDecimal(nbParts), 2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
        return true;
    } catch (ArithmeticException roundingError) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

From the `BigDecimal` javadoc:

> **Throws:**
>
> ArithmeticException - if divisor==0, or roundingMode==RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY and this.scale() is insufficient to represent the result of the division exactly.

You can use it like that:

```
System.out.println(isExactSplit(new BigDecimal("54.2"), 2)); // prints true
System.out.println(isExactSplit(new BigDecimal("61.05"), 2)); // prints false
```

Comment: Unclear BigDecimal is actually needed in this case, but that does depend on the values being tested.

Comment: @keshlam I corrected the answer (I posted it too quickly the first time). I think that it's a good idea to use `BigDecimal` for two reasons: to avoid the problems with the floating point numbers and because it already provides what is needed (check if the scale is sufficient to represent the result of the division).